# Saving Photos in iPhoto to a flashdrive or other device

Tags: backup, photos.app

I would like to back up my photos from my iPhoto Library (right now, I have about 8,000) and all I have available at the moment is a 10G flash drive.

Eventually, I would like to buy an external hard drive to save them to, but that is just not feasible at the moment. How do I save them to a flash drive? Would there be room for all of them? Oh, and I have video clips also.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Export" function in iPhoto.

Located under File in iPhoto menu.

Select your Flash Drive as destination.

You might want to check your 8000 photos and videos total size before doing it.

To see the total size click on the (i) at bottom right or in View menu.